# Scipy Optimization: Pass a function as a constraint with additional arguments (args)

Tags: function, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimize

I have an optimization problem (optimze by changing x[0] and x[1]), where one of the constraints is a function, that uses the same constant variables (a and b) as the optimization function.

```
min f(x, a, b)
  x[0] <= 100
  x[1] <= 500
  g(x, a, b) >= 0.9
```

But I am not sure how to realize the connection between function f and g:

```
x0 = np.array([10, 100])
bnds = ((0, 500), (0, 5000))
arguments = (100, 4)  # This are varibles a and b

cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1]},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: g(x, 100, 4)-0.9})

res = minimize(f, x0, args=arguments, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
print(res.x)

>> x: array([10, 5000])
```

But using this results function g results in

```
g(x,a,b)=0.85434
```

There is an optimal solution with x=[452, 4188], where

```
g(x,a,b)=0.901839
```

How do I need to adapt the constraints, that g(x,a,b) is valid.

Edit: Obviously the optimization is not sucessful:

```
print(res)
>> fun: 1778.86301369863
>> jac: array([1.00019786e+09, 9.31503296e-01])
>> message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
>> nfev: 4
>> nit: 1
>> njev: 1
>> status: 4
>> success: False
>> x: array([ 10., 5000.])
```

Thanks a lot.
UvW

Comment: slsqp is only a local solver with smoothness assumptions, so it is not guaranteed to find optimal or even feasible solutions for arbitrary functions g. You could try different starting points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I know that there might be no optimal solution and I already tried some different starting points. Nevertheless the solution from the algorithm does not fullfill the constraint `g(a, b, x) >= 0.9`. Hence I assume that he algorithm ignore this constraint or did not get the right connection. 
I also tried `{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': g, 'args': arguments}`, which works, but I am not sure how to implement the `>= 0.9` statement here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know anything about `g()`. (Convex? Smooth? Derivatives available?)

Answer (score 1):

`f()` and `g()` are not convex, not smooth and derivates are not available. Nevertheless my questioned aimed for the right syntax (using a function as a constraint). So I tried it with two "simpler" functions (see executeable code below) and it worked. So I assume, that my syntax is right and the problem lies with optimization method "SLSQP".
Is there an optimization method within the SCIPY package (some kind of Evolutionary algorithm) that I can use to solve my problem with `g()` and `f()`

- not convex,
- not smooth and
- derivates are not available?

  ```
  import numpy as np
  from scipy.optimize import minimize

  def g(x, a, b):
      return (x[0]+x[1]+a+b)/100

  def f(x, a, b):
      return (x[0]*a+x[1]*b)*g(x, a, b)

  x0 = np.array([0, 0]) bnds = ((0, 30), (0, 20)) arguments = (2, 3)  # This are varibles a and b

  cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[0]},
  {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x[1]},
  {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: g(x, 2, 3)-0.5}) #<--My question was about the correct syntax of that constraint


  res = minimize(f, x0, args=arguments, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)

  print(res)

  >>  fun: 52.50000000000027
  >>  jac: array([2.05000019, 2.55000019])
  >>  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
  >>  nfev: 20
  >>  nit: 5
  >>  njev: 5
  >>  status: 0
  >>  success: True
  >>  x: array([30., 15.])
  ```